# When I enter $2 and selected 1. The change amount was 0.40 i dont know whats the problem

Tags: python

When I enter $2 and selected 1. The change amount was 0.40 i dont know whats the problem. Below is my code.

This is a vending machine that will 1st allow user to input value then display the option and get user to insert his / her selection. And the machine will calculate how much and how many coins to give back.

```
while True:
    #display welcome message
    print ("Welcome to Fast Snacks vending machine")
    
    coins_inserted = float(input("Please enter the amount of coins you would like to insert: $"))
    
    if coins_inserted > 2:
        print ("Error! Please do not insert more than $2. Try again.")
        continue;
        
    elif coins_inserted == 2:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("1) Calbee                     - $1.80")
        price = float(1.80)
        
        print ("2) Lays Classic Potato Chip   - $2.00")
        price = float(2)
        
        print ("3) Twisties Tomato            - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        price = float(1.20)
        
        print ("5) m&m chocolate              - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        print ("6) Skittles Sour Candy        - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        
    elif coins_inserted >= 1.80:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("1) Calbee                     - $1.80")
        price = float(1.80)
        
        print ("3) Twisties Tomato            - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        price = float(1.20)
        
        print ("5) m&m chocolate              - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        print ("6) Skittles Sour Candy        - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
    
    elif coins_inserted >= 1.6:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("3) Twisties Tomato            - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        price = float(1.20)
        
        print ("5) m&m chocolate              - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        print ("6) Skittles Sour Candy        - $1.60")
        price = float(1.60)
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        
    elif coins_inserted == 1.20:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        price = float(1.20)
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        
    else:
        print ("There aren't enough coins inserted!")
        continue;
        
    # try:
        
    change = coins_inserted - price
    
    print ("$%.2f." %change)
        
    if (selection == 1) or (selection == '01') and (change == .20):
        print ("You've selected 1 - calbee $1.80.")
        print ("1 - 20¢ left. \n")
        print ("Thank you for your purchase! Remember to take your snack and change. \n")
        
    elif (selection == 1) or (selection == '01') and (change == .10):
        print ("1 - 10¢ left. \n")
        print ("Thank you for your purchase! Remember to take your snack and change. \n")
        
    elif (selection == 1) or (selection == '01') and (change == 0):
        print ("No change. \n")
        print ("Thank you for your purchase! Remember to take your snack. \n")
```

Comment: Don't post pictures, copy and paste your code

Comment: @darthbaba done sry didnt use this before.

Comment: What happens here is that all statements in the if or elif block are executed from top to bottom. So price is assigned the value of the first item, then it's overwritten with the value of the second and so on. You will need some kind of logic to select the right value. For example, add the price assignment and change calculation below the `if (selection == 1)` line.

Comment: you need to maintain a dict for items and price then select the price as per the selection

Answer (score 0):

The `price` variable is overwritten several times before it is used, the last time with `1.6`. Therefore `2-price` results in 0.4.

You need a way to assign a different value to `price` *depending on* what the user entered, for example by using `if` statements or a look-up table implemented as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment you need to have a dictionary defined to fetch the price based on the selection from the user. The below code has items and prices dictionary then you can fetch the required information based on the selection.

```
prices = {'1':1.80,'2':2,'3':1.60,'4':1.20,'5':1.60,'6':1.60}
items = {'1':'Calbee','2':'Lays Classic Potato Chip','3':'Twisties Tomato',
        '4':'KitKat Bar','5':'m&m chocolate','6':'Skittles Sour Candy'}

while True:
    #display welcome message
    print ("Welcome to Fast Snacks vending machine")
    
    coins_inserted = float(input("Please enter the amount of coins you would like to insert: $"))
    
    if coins_inserted > 2:
        print ("Error! Please do not insert more than $2. Try again.")
        continue;
        
    elif coins_inserted == 2:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("1) Calbee                     - $1.80")
        
        print ("2) Lays Classic Potato Chip   - $2.00")
        
        print ("3) Twisties Tomato            - $1.60")
        
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        
        print ("5) m&m chocolate              - $1.60")
        
        print ("6) Skittles Sour Candy        - $1.60")
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        price = prices[str(selection)]
        
    elif coins_inserted >= 1.80:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("1) Calbee                     - $1.80")
        
        print ("3) Twisties Tomato            - $1.60")
        
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        
        print ("5) m&m chocolate              - $1.60")
        
        print ("6) Skittles Sour Candy        - $1.60")
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        price = prices[str(selection)]
    
    elif coins_inserted >= 1.6:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("3) Twisties Tomato            - $1.60")
        
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        
        print ("5) m&m chocolate              - $1.60")
        
        print ("6) Skittles Sour Candy        - $1.60")
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        price = prices[str(selection)]
        
    elif coins_inserted == 1.20:
        #display items
        #abstract price
        print ("4) KitKat Bar                 - $1.20")
        
        #Ask user to enter the number they want
        selection = int(input("Enter the number of the item you will want to get: "))
        print ("\n")
        price = prices[str(selection)]
        
    else:
        print ("There aren't enough coins inserted!")
        continue;
        
    # try:
        
    change = coins_inserted - price
    
    print ("$%.2f." %change)

    print ("You've selected {} - {} ${}.".format(selection, items[str(selection)], prices[str(selection)]))
    print ("1 - {}¢ left.".format(round(change,3)))
    print ("Thank you for your purchase! Remember to take your snack and change. \n")
```

Comment: i will not be able to use array, tuples and dictionaries or functions base on the brief. I am so sry just saw this.